# Forward video on a particular location

Tags: html, video

i have a video with duration 10 minutes, also there is 10 buttons. On button click i want to forward video to at particulr position. For example if i click on button 2 video should forward 2 minutes, if i click on button 9 it should go to 9 minute forward.I want make 10 sections in video .Is there any way to get this.

```
  <video width="320" height="240" id="my_video" controls>
   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  </video>
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the answere, it is working for me. On button click set current time

```
     var vid = document.getElementById("my_video");
     function setCurTime() { 
      vid.currentTime=1;
      // here you can set time as 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 as per your need.
      if (vid.paused) {
       vid.play(); 
      }

     }
```